# column decimal point value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, decimal

I run the below query.....

```
SELECT SUM(PAPostedTotalCostN) AS Total_Cost 
FROM PA01201
WHERE PA01201.PAcontid = '00900'
```

which returns the value `12169298.25000`

what is the simplest way to get the query to return any number to two decimals?

using the same return value as an example I would like to see the number appear as `12169298.25`

The query will be used to return many numbers based on 'PAcontid' so i need to have the entire column of 'PAPostedTotalCostN' to be to 2 decimal places

any help much appreciated.

Comment: do you want to display or physically round up, down or mathematically?

Comment: Example the value is `12169298.25000` the result should be `12169298.25`

Comment: While there are many solutions to this problem, display is an issue best handled outside of SQL. If you need to format for later display, and you can do so in your interface (Excel, a web page, etc.) that would usually be preferable, in terms of performance and how the program works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),SUM(PAPostedTotalCostN)) AS Total_Cost 
FROM PA01201
WHERE PA01201.PAcontid = '00900'
```

Comment: perfect.  That's exactly what I wanted.  cheers for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
CAST(PAPostedTotalCostN AS Numeric(12, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx

You can use the ROUND function:

```
ROUND ( numeric_expression , length [ ,function ] )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `CAST` is as a decimal with 2 places:

```
select CAST(PAPostedTotalCostN as decimal(20, 2))
```

Example:

```
declare @t as decimal(20, 5)
set @t = 12169298.250000

select cast(@t as decimal(20, 2))
```

Result:

```
12169298.25
```

This will round the result if the value at the can be rounded, if you do not want it to be rounded:

```
select cast(round(@t, 2, 1) as decimal(20, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.name, CAST( SUM( e.amount * er.tlkarsiligi ) AS DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) ) from ..
```

For It works on Mysql